# How to avoid "Key paths that include an array property must use aggregate operations" exception when querying a Realm?

Tags: swift, realm

I have a Realm object database with the following structure:

```
class ItemModel: Object {
    dynamic var id: Int = 0
    dynamic var catId: Int = 0
    dynamic var subId: Int = 0
    dynamic var itemName: String = ""
    dynamic var sortOrder: Int = 0
    dynamic var favorite: Bool = false

    override static func primaryKey() -> String {
        return "id"
    }
}

class SubCategoryModel: Object {
    dynamic var id: Int = 0
    dynamic var catId: Int = 0
    dynamic var subCatName: String = ""
    dynamic var desc: String = ""
    dynamic var sortOrder: Int = 0
    let haveUnit = List<ItemModel>()

    override static func primaryKey() -> String {
        return "id"
    }
}

class CategoryModel: Object {
    dynamic var id: Int = 0
    dynamic var catName: String = ""
    dynamic var sortOrder: Int = 0

    override static func primaryKey() -> String {
        return "id"
    }
}
```

To query the database I'm using the following code:

```
var data = List<ItemModel>()
let index = indexPath.section
var query = "catId == \(inCategory)"
if (searchTextValue != "") {
    query += " AND itemName CONTAINS[c] \(searchTextValue)"
}
if index == 0 {
    let unitFavorite = DBManager.realm.objects(ItemModel.self).filter("\(query) AND favorite == true")
    data += unitFavorite
} else {
    var subquery = "catId == \(inCategory)"
    if (searchTextValue != "") {
        subquery += " AND ANY haveUnit.itemName CONTAINS[c] %@"
        let subCat = DBManager.realm.objects(SubCategoryModel.self).filter(subquery, searchTextValue).sorted(byKeyPath: "sortOrder", ascending: true)
        data += subCat[indexPath.section - 1].haveUnit
    } else {
        let subCat = DBManager.realm.objects(SubCategoryModel.self).filter(subquery).sorted(byKeyPath: "sortOrder", ascending: true)
        data += subCat[indexPath.section - 1].haveUnit
    }
}
```

When running this code I'm always seeing the following exception:

> Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'Invalid predicate', reason: 'Key paths that include an array property must use aggregate operations'

Can you please help me understand why I'm seeing this exception and what I can do to avoid it?

Comment: Can you please share the final predicate string you're passing to `filter` when the exception is raised? Given the complex logic you're using to build up the predicate string it's hard to determine which code path is being hit and is generating the exception.

Comment: Hey @dodi, have you got any solution for your problem?